# How to avoid flickering effect while jumping from one jdialog to another jdialog

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have created two jdialog box. from first jdialog box i call to second jdialog box.
I have arranged my component at the center. But when i click on next button my program calls the second jdialog but within that period (for a fraction of second i found some flickering effect means some jdialog is displayed at the left top of my screen. its for fraction of second. I think it may be flickering effect. so how to avoid this problem.

Thanks
Sunil KUmar Sahoo

Comment: [-1] - it might have been an interesting question, but the way it is edited makes it impossible to read. Please have some respect for people you expect help from...

Comment: i have posted the complete code but i donot know how it display like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably display the second dialog before you set its location. So instead of doing :

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

do this :

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If one dialog opens another, it might make more sense to use something like a Wizard instead.  Then you avoid flickering altogether as you would change the contents on the component of the one and only dialog that you show on the screen.

The downside is that, of course, it will be a little bit harder to implement, but not much.

The following link contains the information about creating a wizard:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/